# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql

I've just got problem with my code.

```
SELECT *,(SELECT STOPPAYMENT FROM LOAN_TERMS) AS STOP 
FROM SUBS
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Tell us which is the relation between the 2 tables. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Rather than using subquery make use of joins.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery `SELECT STOPPAYMENT FROM LOAN_TERMS` returns more than one row, make sure it returns only one row.

Or try,

```
SELECT *, (SELECT TOP 1 STOPPAYMENT FROM LOAN_TERMS ORDER BY SomeColumn) AS STOP 
FROM SUBS
```

Comment: Um. Their subquery doesn't have `TOP 1` in it, your solution does, so that suggests your first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: Whilst this may fix the error, using `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` is pretty bad advice, and it almost certainly doesn't solve the OPs actual problem (also it'll fail if the OP isn't using SQLServer).

Comment: @OGHaza Updated the answer with `ORDER BY` clause.